# WebApi async Task return timeout

Tags: timeout, breeze, ravendb, asp.net-web-api

I have a durandal breeze and knokouts SPA. The server webapi returns async Task> list that awaits for data from a ravendb server. The call is as usual:

```
var query = EntityQuery.from('Benefits')
                        .orderBy('benefitName');

        return manager.executeQuery(query)
                .then(querySucceeded)
                .fail(queryFailed);
```

It is always returning queryFailed (404 Not found error). It doesn't wait for the data.

If I return a list of hardcoded data from the server with no database connection it works.

Any Idea?

Is it any simple way to set the timeout for the query call?

Comment: Is it any way to set the executeQuery timeout????

Comment: How many records it should return?

Answer (score 1):

## Update 16 May 2014

You can set HTTP-level timeout and cancellation with the AJAX Adapter's `requestInterceptor` as of v.1.4.12. See the documentation, ["Controlling AJAX calls"](http://www.breezejs.com/documentation/controlling-ajax).

## Original answer

You can customize the Breeze AJAX adapter or replace it entirely as described here: http://www.breezejs.com/documentation/customizing-ajax.

If your are using the jQuery ajax adapter  you might try

```
// get the current default Breeze ajax adapter
var ajaxAdapter = breeze.core.config.getAdapterInstance("ajax");
// set fixed headers and timeout
ajaxAdapter.defaultSettings = {
   headers: { 
       "Accept": "application/json, text/javascript, */*; q=0.01"
   }
   timeout: 8000,
};
```

Comment: I had a similar issue but the timeout I got was from the database. I have made the tuning by indexing/statistics and it solved the issue. Does customizing AJAX adapter work for such situations?

Comment: Right now I´m unable to run it. I have customized the timeout and doesn´t work.